# Unable to access array element with json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have used json_decode to get an array from a JSON response:

```
$result = (json_decode($trends,true));
```

which gives me the following (I haven't included all of the EstablishmentDetail array results)

```
Array ( [FHRSEstablishment] => Array ( [Header] => Array ( [#text] => [ExtractDate] => 2012-05-28 [ItemCount] => 5 [ReturnCode] => Success ) [EstablishmentCollection] => Array ( [EstablishmentDetail] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [FHRSID] => 248659 [LocalAuthorityBusinessID] => INS/06/06179 [BusinessName] => Ancient Raj [BusinessType] => Restaurant/Cafe/Canteen [BusinessTypeID] => 1 [AddressLine1] => 26 North Lane, Canterbury, [PostCode] => CT2 7EE [RatingValue] => 3 [RatingKey] => fhrs_3_en-GB [RatingDate] => 2010-11-18 [LocalAuthorityCode] => 180 [LocalAuthorityName] => Canterbury City [Scores] => [SchemeType] => FHRS [Geocode] => )
```

which I thought I' be able to use a foreach to get to the BusinessName:

```
foreach ($result->FHRSEstablishment->EstablishmentCollection->EstablishmentDetail as $detail){
    echo $detail['BusinessName'];
}
```

but I'm not getting any results.

Comment: `$result` is an array, not an object, hence using `->` won't work.

Comment: format your array output if you want more answers.

Comment: Please learn about language features while making use of them: http://php.net/array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're accessing your `$result` as an object:

```
$result->FHRSEstablishment
```

but when you're calling `json_decode` with the second parameter set to `true`, it's returning an associative array, which you should access as:

```
$result['FHRSEstablishment']['EstablishmentCollection'] //...
```

If you want to be able to access your `$result` with object notation, you should define it as:

```
$result = json_decode($trends) //without 2nd parameter = true
```

Comment: thanks very much, I do want it as an array.  Still can't access the associative array, I'll take another look at the array output.